# Logging a user out of my app onStop

Tags: android, security, logout, android-lifecycle

I want to log a user out of app when ever the app is in onStop state, or onDestroy.

Do I have to write logout code for every activity to log the user out of app at that  state?

And at what state in activity life cycle is it best to log a user out of app?

This is for security purpose.

Comment: The question is do you want to log your user out every time she/he leaves the app ? Sounds like bad UX to me, unless it is a security requirement. You can then look at the lifecycle callbacks to decide when you want to log your user out.

Comment: I want to log a user out of the app every time he/she leaves the app for security purpose. And I want the app to log them out in a situation where a user forgets to log off, and the app is then destroyed. At that point I want to clear the shared preference. But I want to know if i have to call on destroy for every activity or just for one activity

Comment: Why don't you write the code for logging out in some helper class and call it from the onStop method for example in order not to copy and paste the same code multiple times.

Comment: That sound like a great idea. But I have to call on stop from every activity not to leave loopholes

Comment: Sounds like a good case to use a base class for every Activity.

Comment: I used a base class and was able to log users out from `onStop()` but nothing happens when I call the `logOut()` function from `onDestroy()` and I noticed calling `logOut()` function form `onClose()` was a terrible idea like @2Dee said. Can anyone tell me the best way to log user out of app if he or she forgets to sign out?

Answer (score 1):

You may find [lifecycle aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html) useful in this instance.

The premise, is that you have a `LifecycleObserver` that you can add to your `Activity`. This component will listen for the step that you wish to log off at. Be it `onStop` or `onDestroy`.

This lets you take the logic out of the `Activity` for handling logouts, letting you keep a common standard across any activities that need this system in place.

Example:

```
public class MyLogoutObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    public void logoutListener() {
        // Code to logout goes here.
    }
}
```

Then you can provide this in your Activity:

```
getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyLogoutObserver());
```

If you need a `Context`, you can construct the observer with that in mind.

Comment: Nothing happens `ON_DESTROY`, and I get an error trying to clear shared preference from MyLogoutObserver. And I notice logging a user out of app from `ON_STOP` is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you positive that it is actually destroyed when you are testing? That can take an indeterminate amount of time.  You could try setting the developer setting to destroy activities immediately. Also, what error?

Answer (score 0):

So I created a helper class like this

```
public class AppController extends Application {
      private static AppController mInstance;

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         mInstance = this;
     }

     public void logOUt(){
         //Log out logic
     }
}
```

Then call `logOut()` from `onStop()` like this

```
 @Override
public void onStop(){

    AppController.getInstance().logOut();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I notice calling `logOut()` from `onStop` was a terrible idea. Can anyone help with a workaround?